# Strange app crash when returning from background

Tags: ios, crash, ios8, sigabrt, sigkill

This appears to be an iOS 8 problem only. I haven't seen it anywhere else, and it only happens  on iOS 8. This is not local to my app, as it seems to affect nearly every app on my phone, including ones that haven't been updated to iOS 8. The crash is a `EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)` which seems to trigger on random threads. The back trace is of no help of course because I can't re-symbolicate the crash reports from different builds and applications. So I decided to run my app in Xcode and recreate events that lead up to this crash. Essentially I just run my app so it's loaded, press the home button to switch to another app, do some stuff on my phone and return back to my app several seconds later. When I did get it to crash, and returned back to my app, instead of getting a `SIGABRT` and getting a stack trace, instead I get a `SIGKILL` and a `(lldb)` message in the console. This is strange because it does not crash while in the background but instead when returning to the foreground so any background process are uninterrupted. And because there is no stack trace, I have no idea why this is happening. To my knowledge, a `SIGKILL` is only given by Xcode when I press the stop button and when an app uses too much memory. Neither events occured. Has any one experienced this and/or solved it?

Comment: If you cannot provide a stack trace then I can't see how anyone can help.  I don't understand your reason for being unable to provide a symbolicated stacktrace; please expand on that.

Comment: @trojanfoe I can't resymbolicate because the crash was on old builds and the DSYM file has been regenerated many more times since the build I experienced the crash on my phone without Xcode on. Also, there is no crash report or stack trace *to* symbolicate when trying with the debug server.